# How to connect an iOS app to SQL server without webservices?

Tags: ios, swift, database-server

I am given a task to retrieve data from a database server.

I have the following details:

```
HOST
PORT
DATABASE
USERNAME
PASSWORD
```

But how can I fire a connection from iOS to the database server directly?

No SOAP/RESTful APIs available.

Comment: Unless the database vendor provides a client library for iOS it is going to be very difficult. Even if there is a client library, this isn't something you would want to do across the Internet. It might be ok on a private network.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: @Paulw11 ok, I know all about the disadvantages, I do not want to do it either, but I am required to do it that way :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For SQL server, you can use this library:
[SQLClient](https://github.com/martinrybak/SQLClient/) by martinrybak

> SQLClient: Native Microsoft SQL Server client for iOS. An Objective-C wrapper around the open-source FreeTDS library.

Comment: Thanks, this is the only available library for this task, but it is very ugly to connect this way. Web services and REST APIs are much much easier. I suggest that no one use it. Instead spend your valuable time on creating a web services or REST API.

Comment: How should i import and use this library my swift project...may you send me an example project. Actually i created bridgingheader import sqlclient.h file and thats all.. how should i go after this..

Comment: Is there any such library for Mac applications too ?

Comment: @AshutoshShukla Shukla have you found such library for MAC applications?

Comment: No, I did not find any!